# Use specified ids for wordpress search and ignore original search query

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I'm working on a wordpress ecommerce website in which the user can search for keywords, and products are returned to the user. However, wordpress's default search is super slow, so I'm using a custom endpoint to return ids of products. Using these ids, I need to simply tell Wordpress to forget its current query and just display those post ids. This feels like something that should be extremely simple, but I've been pulling my hair out for hours to try and get this working.

I've tried several things, for example modifying the search query and setting 'post__in' to the array of post ids, but this doesn't work because this still requires wordpress to run it's full query before checking if the query values contain those ids. I need the wordpress query to completely be overwritten. So, I've tried adding a new WP_Query inside of a 'pre_get_posts' with 'post__in' in the query args and returning that query instead of the original, but that also doesn't work.

I've also tried unsetting the 's' variable for both query and query_vars as well as setting is_search to false, but that definitely didn't work. I even tried using 'query_posts' hook to try and modify the sql directly, but this proved to have the same problem as another attempt above. The query still had to run first, and that's part of the problem.

There was a similar question asked here, but no answer was ever given. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/override-pre_get_posts-to-give-specific-ids-to-fetch/ This sounds almost identical to what I'm attempting to do, so it's unfortunate that the post got closed.

Perhaps 'pre_get_posts' in the functions.php file isn't the right way to go, but I'm at a loss as to what to do next.

The site this is for is also using woocommerce. Also, I'm pretty new to Wordpress, so this may very well be something simple that I'm missing.

I just found this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36687#no0 that may lead me in the right direction. I'm still testing it, but hopefully it's what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to find the answer. Instead of using the `pre_get_posts` filter, I used the `posts_pre_query`. Unlike `pre_get_posts`, `posts_per_query` completely stops the wp_query and allows you to either provide an array of posts or an array of post ids to the filter. If those arrays are null, the original query will run so it's super easy to conditionally run the default query if necessary. This was an extremely helpful filter and unbelievably difficult to get any information on. I'm happy I got this solved though.

Edit: This approach still has its issues. Mainly pagination, or at least in my case. I'm still trying to figure out how to get pagination to work properly.